# Unity Mesh Renderer won't be completely transparent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, opacity

I'm creating a script that allows objects to be faded considering an interval of time.

The script works very well, however when an object is faded, it is still very visible in the inspector AND in the build.

Could someone explain me why and how to make an object completely invisible?
(I know I can "enable" the object, but isn't it using more resources than fading? I don't know :( )

Here is the code if I've made any mistake (code inspired from a topic in unity's forum)

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    MyTime = Time.deltaTime;
    AccumulatedTime += MyTime;
    if (this.name == "Cube (1)")
    {
        Debug.Log(AccumulatedTime);
    }
    if (SwitchVisibility == 1)
    {

        if (AccumulatedTime >= Interval && AccumulatedTime<= 2*Interval || AccumulatedTime >= 3*Interval && AccumulatedTime<= 4*Interval)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeTo(0.0f, 1.0f));
            SwitchVisibility = 0;
        }
    }
    if (SwitchVisibility == 0)
    {
        if (AccumulatedTime >= 0 && AccumulatedTime <= Interval || AccumulatedTime >= 2*Interval && AccumulatedTime <= 3*Interval)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeTo(1.0f, 1.0f));
            SwitchVisibility = 1;
        }
    }
    if (AccumulatedTime >= Interval * 4.5f)
    {
        AccumulatedTime = 0;
    }
}

IEnumerator FadeTo(float aValue, float aTime)
{
    float alpha = MyRenderer.material.color.a;
    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime / aTime)
    {
        OriginalColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(alpha, aValue, t);
        Color newColor = OriginalColor;
        MyRenderer.material.color = newColor;  
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Here is what objects look like:

[image]

Comment: What is the `aValue` and `aTime` variable in the `FadeTo` function? Also, do you want to just fade over time provided? Do you also want to make the object appear at some point?

Comment: aTime is the value used to divide Time.DeltaTime in the "for" statement. It sets the speed to fade the object.

I fade every "interval" seconds (interval set in editor).

I may not have explained the problem correctly, my question is that I want to make it completely invisible, the code works well (Well, even if it does not make the object invisible)

Comment: Why not put  `Debug.Log(alpha)` and see if that value is actually 0. That will help troubleshoot your code. Tell me the outcome. I get it. No, your code does not work correctly. Let me know the output of `Debug.Log(alpha)`

Comment: Grmbl, I don't know why I haven't think about it...

You are right, alpha is at 0.006000... Why isn't it at 0?

Comment: I guess that is because of float and floating point imprecision. Generally it's a good idea to just set it to min/max value at some threshold. Something like `if alpha <= 0.01 -> alpha = 0`.

Comment: Done it, still the same. Moreover I tried to set alpha at 0 in the editor, it is still visible. I guess it is not possible to have an invisible object this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your code is fine, the problem very likely is from your Material settings. This changed in Unity 5. To change the alpha of a `Mesh Renderer`, you must also change the Material's **Rendering Mode** from **Opaque**(default) to **Fade**.

*Transparent Mode is also fine but will will not be completely transparent and will result to the problem in your question*.

You can change the mode from script.

**Property Name**: `_Mode`

With `Debug.Log(MyRenderer.material.GetFloat("_Mode"));`, I got the follwing values:

```
0 = Opaque
1 = Cutout
2 = Fade
3 = Transparent
```

We can change the **Rendering Mode** to Fade with `MyRenderer.material.SetFloat("_Mode",2);`

There is a known [problem](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/access-rendering-mode-var-on-standard-shader-via-scripting.287002/) when setting the Render Mode from script. You must also update all other properties as well to make the change take effect. Here is a complete way to change your Render Mode to Fade from script:

```
MyRenderer.material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2);
MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
MyRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
MyRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
MyRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
MyRenderer.material.renderQueue = 3000;
```

Finally, if the this is working for you then your script is not good. You can use the script below to fade in and fade out a Mesh Renderer.

```
public MeshRenderer MyRenderer;
bool fading = false;

void Fade(bool fadeIn, float duration)
{
    if (fading)
    {
        return;
    }
    fading = true;

    changeModeToFade();
    StartCoroutine(FadeTo(fadeIn, duration));
}

void changeModeToFade()
{
    MyRenderer.material.SetFloat("_Mode", 2);
    MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
    MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
    MyRenderer.material.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
    MyRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHATEST_ON");
    MyRenderer.material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
    MyRenderer.material.DisableKeyword("_ALPHAPREMULTIPLY_ON");
    MyRenderer.material.renderQueue = 3000;
}

IEnumerator FadeTo(bool fadeIn, float duration)
{
    //MyRenderer.material.
    float counter = 0f;

    //Set Values depending on if fadeIn or fadeOut
    float a, b;
    if (fadeIn)
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 0;
    }


    //Enable MyRenderer component
    if (!MyRenderer.enabled)
        MyRenderer.enabled = true;

    //Get original Mesh Color
    Color meshColor = MyRenderer.material.color;


    //Do the actual fading
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        float alpha = Mathf.Lerp(a, b, counter / duration);
        Debug.Log(alpha);


        MyRenderer.material.color = new Color(meshColor.r, meshColor.g, meshColor.b, alpha);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!fadeIn)
    {
        //Disable Mesh Renderer
        MyRenderer.enabled = false;
    }
    fading = false; //So that we can call this function next time
}

void Start()
{
    //Fade(true, 3f); //Fade In
    Fade(false, 3f);//Fade Out
}
```